# how to install a certificate in WP10

Tags: certificate

How I install a certificate on WP10. Before in WP8.1 I could email it to myself and execute it. Now Outlook says it cannot run as isa risky file.
Marcin

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this by hooking it to my computer by usb. I transferred the files to my documents folder. Then I used a program called "files" that I got from the app store. I used the files program to navigate to the cer file. Then it opened and installed. Now I can use self signed certs from my company domain.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do this.

- Zip the cert and email it to yourself, open the zip, and tap on the cert in the zip viewer app.
- Transfer the cert file using USB, and then use a file browser app to open it on the phone.
- Send the cert file to your phone using Bluetooth (pretty easy if the phone is synched to your PC via Bluetooth; right-click in Explorer and select `Send To` -> `Bluetooth device`).
- Send the file to OneDrive and open it using the app on your phone.
- Send the file over some other app (Messenger, maybe Skype, etc.) that doesn't have Outlook's (mildly absurd) restriction on such files.
- If the file is hosted online anywhere, open it in the phone's web browser. This works even if you have to tell the browser to ignore an untrusted certificate just to load the page where the cert is hosted.
- If this cert is for a business, your IT people may be able to push the certificate to your phone if the phone is enrolled for mobile device management (business account set up on the phone).

Hope that helps!